# What are these 4 red spots on the A-10?

Tags: aircraft-marking, fairchild-a-10

What are these 4 spots on the wings and fuselage of the A-10? I can't seem to find a closer shot of their wings but each spot looks like a small target with a dot and an outer circle, mostly in red, but some are in black.

[image: From Wikipedia Commons]

[image: From The Drive]

[image: From VRWorld]

Comment: They put those there for the enemy to target and become disheartened after scoring direct hits on all four of them and she still flies.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I am fairly sure that these are the fuel hatches. They are placed right over the wing and main fuselage fuel tanks. (The hatches are where the fuel is put into the craft, not drawn out for sampling). During ground fueling, the hatches are used to refill the tanks.

Comment: Yes, @Nicholas is correct, they are fuel tank caps. Normal ground refuelling is in the left wing pylon but if you don't have the proper equipment you can gravity fuel just like any other fuel tank. Two wing tanks, two fuselage tanks.

Comment: See #84 on [this drawing](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e7/b7/08/e7b708e24984c98b3779e049cda5d112.jpg)

Comment: Yeah: I immediately thought 'fuel caps' and it appears to be the correct answer. (Never seen them called "fuel hatches" but I suppose that has to do with what form of English one is using?)

Answer (score 2):

Nicholas got the geist of this one.  The red circles are marking on the four gravity fill fuel tank ports.  The A-10 also uses a pressure fueling port is located on the port landing gear fairing behind an enclosure for most refueling since it is easier and faster.